# Create custom data_collator for Huggingface Trainer

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets

I need to create a custom `data_collator` for finetuning with Huggingface `Trainer API`.

HuggingFace offers `DataCollatorForWholeWordMask` for masking whole words within the sentences with a given probability.

```
model_ckpt    = "vinai/bertweet-base"
tokenizer     = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_ckpt, normalization=True)
data_collator = DataCollatorForWholeWordMask(tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm_probability=args.mlm_prob)
```

I am using the collator as `Trainer` argument:

```
    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=tokenized_dataset['train'],
        eval_dataset=None,
        data_collator=data_collator,
    )
    trainer.train()
```

But in my usecase, a sample input looks like: `<sent1>.<sent2>`. I want to mask the tokens only in `<sent2>` and not in `<sent1>`. How can I go about it? Any pointers on getting started with it are also welcome.